# Provide datasource bean in test - with qualifier

Tags: java, spring

In my service, I'm using:

```
public MyService(@Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource dataSource);
```

So I need to provide datasource bean with name: "secondDataSource". Spring in test provide default datasource by `@AutoConfigureDataJpa` annotation. But how to change its qualifier?

In test I tried:

```
@MockBean(name="secondDataSource")
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Code above, return get connection error on provided datasource (I suppose that, DI for autowired datasource is executed after add bean to context)

Have you any other ideas?

Comment: You will need to register mock behavior. Default is to return `null`.

Comment: @M.Deinum i want to provide default datasource which is created by spring in test by AutoConfigureDataJpa annotation

Comment: Then don't use a mock.

Comment: @M.Deinum But how to tell spring, that default datasource which is provided, is the same as secondDataSource qualifier?

Comment: Use `AutoConfigureTestDatabase` not `AutoconfigureDataJpa`.